# UPS Shipping API: Getting Error of Not found in SoapFault object

Tags: php, api, opencart, ups

I downloaded the Shipping PHP example from ups.com. I am trying to integrate this in Opencart CMS. I want that when the admin enters the order id then with help of API i want to generate the tracking code.

Right now i am using the test shipping values in the parameter arguments. Once the code works properly i will make them dynamic according to order id.

But when I run the code I am getting an exception of not found. I looked at the documentation of UPS but the documentation is not well written and I didn't find the reason for the error. Here is the exception output:

```
    SoapFault Object
    (
        [message:protected] => Not Found
        [string:Exception:private] => 
        [code:protected] => 0
        [file:protected] => my_opencart_root_path/admin/controller/sale/ups_shipping.php
        [line:protected] => 50
        [trace:Exception:private] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [function] => __doRequest
                        [class] => SoapClient
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 
    nonvalidateTest Product for shipping APIMy StoreShipperZs Attn Name12345611155547581Your Shipper Number2311 York RdTimoniumMD21093USHappy Dog Pet SupplyShip To Attention Name9225377171GOERLITZER STR.1Neuss41456DET and T Designs1160b_7412345678902311 York RdTimoniumMD21093US0106471699528764062512/20138642010 warsaw roadRoswellGA30076US08Expedited01Sold To NameSold To Attn Name123456789012340134 Queen StFrankfurt60547DEProduct 1147BOXBOX478111222AAUSLBSLBS10asdf12320151225999jjj777CFRSaleYour CommentsYour Declaration Statement1005020050MiscUSD02NailsINInches752LBSPounds10

                                [1] => http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/UPSS/v1.0
                                [2] => http://onlinetools.ups.com/webservices/ShipBinding/v1.0
                                [3] => 1
                                [4] => 0
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => my_opencart_root_path/admin/controller/sale/ups_shipping.php
                        [line] => 50
                        [function] => __soapCall
                        [class] => SoapClient
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => ProcessShipment
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [Request] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [RequestOption] => nonvalidate
                                                    )

                                                [Shipment] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [Description] => Test Product for shipping API
                                                        [Shipper] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [Name] => My Store
                                                                [AttentionName] => ShipperZs Attn Name
                                                                [TaxIdentificationNumber] => 123456
                                                                [ShipperNumber] => Your Shipper Number
                                                                [Address] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [AddressLine] => 2311 York Rd
                                                                        [City] => Timonium
                                                                        [StateProvinceCode] => MD
                                                                        [PostalCode] => 21093
                                                                        [CountryCode] => US
                                                                    )

                                                                [Phone] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [Number] => 1115554758
                                                                        [Extension] => 1
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                        [ShipTo] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [Name] => Happy Dog Pet Supply
                                                                [AttentionName] => Ship To Attention Name
                                                                [Address] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [AddressLine] => GOERLITZER STR.1
                                                                        [City] => Neuss
                                                                        [PostalCode] => 41456
                                                                        [CountryCode] => DE
                                                                    )

                                                                [Phone] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [Number] => 9225377171
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                        [ShipFrom] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [Name] => T and T Designs
                                                                [AttentionName] => 1160b_74
                                                                [Address] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [AddressLine] => 2311 York Rd
                                                                        [City] => Timonium
                                                                        [StateProvinceCode] => MD
                                                                        [PostalCode] => 21093
                                                                        [CountryCode] => US
                                                                    )

                                                                [Phone] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [Number] => 1234567890
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                        [PaymentInformation] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [ShipmentCharge] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [Type] => 01
                                                                        [BillShipper] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                                [CreditCard] => Array
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        [Type] => 06
                                                                                        [Number] => 4716995287640625
                                                                                        [SecurityCode] => 864
                                                                                        [ExpirationDate] => 12/2013
                                                                                        [Address] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                                [AddressLine] => 2010 warsaw road
                                                                                                [City] => Roswell
                                                                                                [StateProvinceCode] => GA
                                                                                                [PostalCode] => 30076
                                                                                                [CountryCode] => US
                                                                                            )

                                                                                    )

                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                        [Service] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [Code] => 08
                                                                [Description] => Expedited
                                                            )

                                                        [ShipmentServiceOptions] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [InternationalForms] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [FormType] => 01
                                                                        [InvoiceNumber] => asdf123
                                                                        [InvoiceDate] => 20151225
                                                                        [PurchaseOrderNumber] => 999jjj777
                                                                        [TermsOfShipment] => CFR
                                                                        [ReasonForExport] => Sale
                                                                        [Comments] => Your Comments
                                                                        [DeclarationStatement] => Your Declaration Statement
                                                                        [Contacts] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                                [SoldTo] => Array
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        [Option] => 01
                                                                                        [AttentionName] => Sold To Attn Name
                                                                                        [Name] => Sold To Name
                                                                                        [Phone] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                                [Number] => 1234567890
                                                                                                [Extension] => 1234
                                                                                            )

                                                                                        [Address] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                                [AddressLine] => 34 Queen St
                                                                                                [City] => Frankfurt
                                                                                                [PostalCode] => 60547
                                                                                                [CountryCode] => DE
                                                                                            )

                                                                                    )

                                                                            )

                                                                        [Product] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                                [Description] => Product 1
                                                                                [CommodityCode] => 111222AA
                                                                                [OriginCountryCode] => US
                                                                                [Unit] => Array
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        [Number] => 147
                                                                                        [Value] => 478
                                                                                        [UnitOfMeasurement] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                                [Code] => BOX
                                                                                                [Description] => BOX
                                                                                            )

                                                                                    )

                                                                                [ProductWeight] => Array
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        [Weight] => 10
                                                                                        [UnitOfMeasurement] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                                [Code] => LBS
                                                                                                [Description] => LBS
                                                                                            )

                                                                                    )

                                                                            )

                                                                        [Discount] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                                [MonetaryValue] => 100
                                                                            )

                                                                        [FreightCharges] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                                [MonetaryValue] => 50
                                                                            )

                                                                        [InsuranceCharges] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                                [MonetaryValue] => 200
                                                                            )

                                                                        [OtherCharges] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                                [MonetaryValue] => 50
                                                                                [Description] => Misc
                                                                            )

                                                                        [CurrencyCode] => USD
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                        [Package] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [Description] => 
                                                                [Packaging] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [Code] => 02
                                                                        [Description] => Nails
                                                                    )

                                                                [Dimensions] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [UnitOfMeasurement] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                                [Code] => IN
                                                                                [Description] => Inches
                                                                            )

                                                                        [Length] => 7
                                                                        [Width] => 5
                                                                        [Height] => 2
                                                                    )

                                                                [PackageWeight] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [UnitOfMeasurement] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                                [Code] => LBS
                                                                                [Description] => Pounds
                                                                            )

                                                                        [Weight] => 10
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                        [LabelSpecification] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [LabelImageFormat] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [Code] => GIF
                                                                        [Description] => GIF
                                                                    )

                                                                [HTTPUserAgent] => Mozilla/4.5
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => my_opencart_root_path/system/storage/modification/system/engine/action.php
                        [line] => 51
                        [function] => index
                        [class] => ControllerSaleUpsShipping
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )
                )

        [previous:Exception:private] => 
        [faultstring] => Not Found
        [faultcode] => HTTP
    )
```

Here is the controller code which i created:

```
    <?php
class ControllerSaleUpsShipping extends Controller {
    //Configuration
    private $access = "my_access_key";
    private $userid = "my_ups_userid";
    private $passwd = "my_ups_password";
    private $wsdl = HTTPS_UPS."Ship.wsdl";
    private $operation = "ProcessShipment";
    private $endpointurl = 'http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/UPSS/v1.0';
    private $outputFileName = HTTPS_UPS."XOLTResult.txt";

    public function index()
    {
        try
        {
            $opts = array(
                'http' => array(
                    'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
                )
            );
            $context = stream_context_create($opts);
            $mode = array
            (
                'soap_version' => 'SOAP_1_1',  // use soap 1.1 client
                'trace' => 1,
                'stream_context' => $context
            );

            // initialize soap client
            $client = new SoapClient($this->wsdl , $mode);

            //set endpoint url
            $client->__setLocation($this->endpointurl);


            //create soap header
            $usernameToken['Username'] = $this->userid;
            $usernameToken['Password'] = $this->passwd;
            $serviceAccessLicense['AccessLicenseNumber'] = $this->access;
            $upss['UsernameToken'] = $this->usernameToken;
            $upss['ServiceAccessToken'] = $this->serviceAccessLicense;

            $header = new SoapHeader('http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/UPSS/v1.0','UPSSecurity',$upss);
            $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

            if(strcmp($this->operation,"ProcessShipment") == 0 )
            {
                //get response
            $resp = $client->__soapCall('ProcessShipment',array($this->processShipment()));
                 //get status
                echo "Response Status: " . $resp->Response->ResponseStatus->Description ."\n";

                //save soap request and response to file
                $fw = fopen($this->outputFileName , 'w');
                fwrite($fw , "Request: \n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n");
                fwrite($fw , "Response: \n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "\n");
                fclose($fw);

            }
            else if (strcmp($this->operation , "ProcessShipConfirm") == 0)
            {
                    //get response
            $resp = $client->__soapCall('ProcessShipConfirm',array($this->processShipConfirm()));

                 //get status
                echo "Response Status: " . $resp->Response->ResponseStatus->Description ."\n";

                //save soap request and response to file
                $fw = fopen($this->outputFileName , 'w');
                fwrite($fw , "Request: \n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n");
                fwrite($fw , "Response: \n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "\n");
                fclose($fw);

            }
            else
            {
                $resp = $client->__soapCall('ProcessShipeAccept',array($this->processShipAccept()));

                //get status
                echo "Response Status: " . $resp->Response->ResponseStatus->Description ."\n";

            //save soap request and response to file
            $fw = fopen($this->outputFileName ,'w');
            fwrite($fw , "Request: \n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n");
                fwrite($fw , "Response: \n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "\n");
                fclose($fw);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $ex)
        {
            echo "<pre>";print_r ($ex);echo "</pre>";
        }
    }

    public function processShipment()
    {
        //create soap request
        $requestoption['RequestOption'] = 'nonvalidate';
        $request['Request'] = $requestoption;

        $shipment['Description'] = 'Test Product for shipping API';
        $shipper['Name'] = 'Furniture Store';
        $shipper['AttentionName'] = 'ShipperZs Attn Name';
        $shipper['TaxIdentificationNumber'] = '123456';
        $shipper['ShipperNumber'] = 'Your Shipper Number';
        $address['AddressLine'] = '2311 York Rd';
        $address['City'] = 'Timonium';
        $address['StateProvinceCode'] = 'MD';
        $address['PostalCode'] = '21093';
        $address['CountryCode'] = 'US';
        $shipper['Address'] = $address;
        $phone['Number'] = '1115554758';
        $phone['Extension'] = '1';
        $shipper['Phone'] = $phone;
        $shipment['Shipper'] = $shipper;

        $shipto['Name'] = 'Happy Dog Pet Supply';
        $shipto['AttentionName'] = 'Ship To Attention Name';
        $addressTo['AddressLine'] = 'GOERLITZER STR.1';
        $addressTo['City'] = 'Neuss';
        $addressTo['PostalCode'] = '41456';
        $addressTo['CountryCode'] = 'DE';
        $phone2['Number'] = '9225377171';
        $shipto['Address'] = $addressTo;
        $shipto['Phone'] = $phone2;
        $shipment['ShipTo'] = $shipto;

        $shipfrom['Name'] = 'T and T Designs';
        $shipfrom['AttentionName'] = '1160b_74';
        $addressFrom['AddressLine'] = '2311 York Rd';
        $addressFrom['City'] = 'Timonium';
        $addressFrom['StateProvinceCode'] = 'MD';
        $addressFrom['PostalCode'] = '21093';
        $addressFrom['CountryCode'] = 'US';
        $phone3['Number'] = '1234567890';
        $shipfrom['Address'] = $addressFrom;
        $shipfrom['Phone'] = $phone3;
        $shipment['ShipFrom'] = $shipfrom;

        $shipmentcharge['Type'] = '01';
        $creditcard['Type'] = '06';
        $creditcard['Number'] = '4716995287640625';
        $creditcard['SecurityCode'] = '864';
        $creditcard['ExpirationDate'] = '12/2013';
        $creditCardAddress['AddressLine'] = '2010 warsaw road';
        $creditCardAddress['City'] = 'Roswell';
        $creditCardAddress['StateProvinceCode'] = 'GA';
        $creditCardAddress['PostalCode'] = '30076';
        $creditCardAddress['CountryCode'] = 'US';
        $creditcard['Address'] = $creditCardAddress;
        $billshipper['CreditCard'] = $creditcard;
        $shipmentcharge['BillShipper'] = $billshipper;
        $paymentinformation['ShipmentCharge'] = $shipmentcharge;
        $shipment['PaymentInformation'] = $paymentinformation;

        $service['Code'] = '08';
        $service['Description'] = 'Expedited';
        $shipment['Service'] = $service;

        $internationalForm['FormType'] = '01';
        $internationalForm['InvoiceNumber'] = 'asdf123';
        $internationalForm['InvoiceDate'] = '20151225';
        $internationalForm['PurchaseOrderNumber'] = '999jjj777';
        $internationalForm['TermsOfShipment'] = 'CFR';
        $internationalForm['ReasonForExport'] = 'Sale';
        $internationalForm['Comments'] = 'Your Comments';
        $internationalForm['DeclarationStatement'] = 'Your Declaration Statement';
        $soldTo['Option'] = '01';
        $soldTo['AttentionName'] = 'Sold To Attn Name';
        $soldTo['Name'] = 'Sold To Name';
        $soldToPhone['Number'] = '1234567890';
        $soldToPhone['Extension'] = '1234';
        $soldTo['Phone'] = $soldToPhone;
        $soldToAddress['AddressLine'] = '34 Queen St';
        $soldToAddress['City'] = 'Frankfurt';
        $soldToAddress['PostalCode'] = '60547';
        $soldToAddress['CountryCode'] = 'DE';
        $soldTo['Address'] = $soldToAddress;
        $contact['SoldTo'] = $soldTo;
        $internationalForm['Contacts'] = $contact;
        $product['Description'] = 'Product 1';
        $product['CommodityCode'] = '111222AA';
        $product['OriginCountryCode'] = 'US';
        $unitProduct['Number'] = '147';
        $unitProduct['Value'] = '478';
        $uom['Code'] = 'BOX';
        $uom['Description'] = 'BOX';
        $unitProduct['UnitOfMeasurement'] = $uom;
        $product['Unit'] = $unitProduct;
        $productWeight['Weight'] = '10';
        $uomForWeight['Code'] = 'LBS';
        $uomForWeight['Description'] = 'LBS';
        $productWeight['UnitOfMeasurement'] = $uomForWeight;
        $product['ProductWeight'] = $productWeight;
        $internationalForm['Product'] = $product;
        $discount['MonetaryValue'] = '100';
        $internationalForm['Discount'] = $discount;
        $freight['MonetaryValue'] = '50';
        $internationalForm['FreightCharges'] = $freight;
        $insurance['MonetaryValue'] = '200';
        $internationalForm['InsuranceCharges'] = $insurance;
        $otherCharges['MonetaryValue'] = '50';
        $otherCharges['Description'] = 'Misc';
        $internationalForm['OtherCharges'] = $otherCharges;
        $internationalForm['CurrencyCode'] = 'USD';
        $shpServiceOptions['InternationalForms'] = $internationalForm;
        $shipment['ShipmentServiceOptions'] = $shpServiceOptions;


        $package['Description'] = '';
        $packaging['Code'] = '02';
        $packaging['Description'] = 'Nails';
        $package['Packaging'] = $packaging;
        $unit['Code'] = 'IN';
        $unit['Description'] = 'Inches';
        $dimensions['UnitOfMeasurement'] = $unit;
        $dimensions['Length'] = '7';
        $dimensions['Width'] = '5';
        $dimensions['Height'] = '2';
        $package['Dimensions'] = $dimensions;
        $unit2['Code'] = 'LBS';
        $unit2['Description'] = 'Pounds';
        $packageweight['UnitOfMeasurement'] = $unit2;
        $packageweight['Weight'] = '10';
        $package['PackageWeight'] = $packageweight;
        $shipment['Package'] = $package;

        $labelimageformat['Code'] = 'GIF';
        $labelimageformat['Description'] = 'GIF';
        $labelspecification['LabelImageFormat'] = $labelimageformat;
        $labelspecification['HTTPUserAgent'] = 'Mozilla/4.5';
        $shipment['LabelSpecification'] = $labelspecification;
        $request['Shipment'] = $shipment;

        echo "Request.......\n";
        print_r($request);
        echo "\n\n";
        return $request;

    }

    function processShipConfirm()
    {

    //create soap request

    }

    function processShipAccept()
    {
    //create soap request
    }
}
?>
```

Can anyone help me where i am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong endpoint.

- SOAP endpoint url for testing (CIE) should be: https://wwwcie.ups.com/webservices/
- And for production applications should be: https://onlinetools.ups.com/webservices/

In your code you've got:

```
private $endpointurl = 'http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/UPSS/v1.0';
...

$client->__setLocation($this->endpointurl);
```

Change your `$endpointurl` property to one of the above.  Also you probably need to make sure your wsdl contains the correct endpoints as well.  These come out of the box with the testing endpoints in a block at the end that looks like this:

```
<!-- Ship Web Service-->
<wsdl:service name="ShipService">
    <wsdl:port name="ShipPort" binding="tns:ShipBinding">
        <!-- Production URL -->
        <!-- <soap:address location="https://onlinetools.ups.com/webservices/Ship"/> -->
        <!-- CIE (Customer Integration Environment) URL -->
        <soap:address location="https://wwwcie.ups.com/webservices/Ship"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

So once your app is production ready you'd uncomment the first address there and comment out the second.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. The documentation of UPS is not so user-friendly and I didn't find to get this issue fixed. Thanks, you saved my time :)

Comment: Can you please tell me that did I pointed the $Outpurfilename to correct file? In my code, I tried with both absolute and relative path to XOLTResult.xml file. But when I run my code, nothing prints in XOLTResult.xml file. So i doubt that might be i am pointing to wrong file or URL.

Comment: might be due to permissions issue.  it's beyond the scope of this question.  if you need help with that, i suggest posting another question